# I would like to develop Calendar which swipe able and need to show previous current and next month names in Tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-calendar, fragmentpageradapter

Can you please suggest me how to develop a calendar app using viewpager and Tablayout. Where there will be three tabs to show previous, current, next month names..!! i did not start developing, i'm fresher to android so need to know to start this

Comment: U need tabs with images or Text?

Comment: Only month names, No images

Comment: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

I think this library will be in help for you
https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView

As you see you could manage to set buttons for next and prev or you could swipe I used this library in many projects